# TypeORM migrations cannot detect changes

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

Have trouble with TypeOrm migrations. I add column to User entity, run command for generate migration and it shows - *No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command*. But there isn't such column in db. When I delete whole User table in db and generate migration after that it works as expectable. So it generates migration correctly when I create new entity but when I add some column to exist entity or change some column it doesn't work.

ormconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "database": "figrea",
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "postgres",
  "entities": [
    "D:\\work\\figrea\\figrea-api\\src\\entities\\**\\**.entity{.ts,.js}"
  ],
  "synchronize": false,
  "schema": "public",
  "logging": false,
  "subscribers": [],
  "migrationsTableName": "migrations",
  "connectTimeoutMS": 180000,
  "migrations": [
    "migration/development/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "migration/development"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to rebuild the project so TypeORM can correctly pick up the changes. I know is kind of late but it may help others.